# Label в Canvas залезает за пределы окна

Tags: c#, canvas, label

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть `Canvas` и в нем по координатам X расположены даты. Так вот, правая дата 12.01.2017 расположена в окне `Canvas`, но сам `Label` вылазит за пределы. Как можно это пофиксить? Можно, конечно, сделать проверку на длину `Label` и если он выходит за размер окна, мы не записываем, но можно ли сделать, чтобы он отрисовывал, но только ту часть, которая в окне? Т.е. мы бы видели только `12.`, всё остальное было бы за окном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, определите вашему `Canvas`'у атрибут `ClipToBounds="True"`.

Comment: Так просто в итоге) Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Fresto: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло :)